# Jpa update get result

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

Is it possible to know if the update was done correctly, at least one data was updated?

```
    public void userForgetPassword(String email) {

    String resetPasswordKey = ...;

    userRepository.userForgetPassword(email, resetPasswordKey);

    mailService.sendHtmlMail(email);

}

@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.resetKey=:resetKey, u.enabled=false where u.username=:email")
void userForgetPassword(@Param("email") String email, @Param("resetPasswordKey") String resetPasswordKey);
```

Because i would like to send email only if update has worked.

I can verify email before update... but i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an `int` instead of `void`. The number returned specifies the number of modified rows.

```java
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.resetKey=:resetKey, u.enabled=false where u.username=:email")
int userForgetPassword(@Param("email") String email, @Param("resetPasswordKey") String resetPasswordKey);
```

See example at [Update Queries With @Modifying](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#update-queries-with-modifying)